# Convergence conditions of the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{cx}}{1+e^{x}} dx$.

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, contour-integration, complex-integration

I want to find the conditions such that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{cx}}{1+e^{x}} dx$  converges.

I am considering as contour the rectangle with vertices $\pm R$, $\pm R + 2\pi i$.

\begin{align*}
\left|\int_{R}^{R+2 \pi i} f(z) \, dz\right|
&= \left|\int_{R}^{R+2 \pi i} \frac{e^{cz}}{1+e^{z}} \, dz\right|
= \left|\int_{0}^{2 \pi i} \frac{e^{c(z+R)}}{1+e^{z+R}} \, dz\right| \\
&\leq \max_{0 \leq z \leq 2 \pi i} \left| \frac{e^{c(z+R)}}{1+e^{z+R}} \right| \cdot 2 \pi
= \frac{e^{c(2 \pi i+R)}}{1+e^{2 \pi i+R}} \cdot 2 \pi \\
&= \frac{2 \pi}{1+e^{R}} e^{cR} e^{c \cdot 2 \pi i} \to 0 \qquad \text{ as } R \to \infty \text{ for } c < 1
\end{align*}

And in the same way

\begin{align*}
\left|\int_{-R+2 \pi i}^{-R} f(z) \, dz\right|
&= \left|\int_{-R + 2 \pi i}^{-R} \frac{e^{cz}}{1+e^{z}} \, dz\right|
= \left|-\int_{0}^{2 \pi i} \frac{e^{c(z-R)}}{1+e^{z-R}} \, dz \right|\\
&\leq \max_{0 \leq z \leq 2 \pi i} \left|\frac{e^{c(z-R)}}{1+e^{z-R}}\right| \cdot 2 \pi \\
&= \frac{2 \pi}{1 + e^{-R}} e^{-cR} e^{c \cdot 2 \pi i} \to 0 \qquad \text{ as } R \to \infty \text{ for } c > 1
\end{align*}

So I am not be able to find values for the real parameter c such that the integral converges as the results $c > 1$ and $c < 1$ contradict each other. I am wondering what is going wrong.

Comment: I am not sure why you are looking at contour integrals when $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{cx}}{e^x+1}\,\mathrm{d}x$ is a bona-fide real integral.

Comment: As I am calculating the integral by looking at some contour.

Comment: For the convergence of $\int\limits_0^\infty$ you need $c<1,$ while for the convergence of $\int\limits_{-\infty}^0$ you need $c>0.$ So $0<c<1$ gives the convergence.

Comment: @LauravanLeuven, I wouldn't say that is an incorrect approach, but convergence can be tested easily only using real analysis. (Considering that you still need to invoke real analysis in order to test for the convergence of the contour integrals, I would rather stick to the original integral.)

Comment: @SangchulLee the exercise is to use that rectangle as contour.

Comment: I am doubting about the maximum values. Are these correct?

Comment: You may need to use contour integrals to *find the value of* the integral, but you are not forced to use contour integrals to test for the convergence. But if you are desperate for contour-integral-based approach to testing for convergence, you may argue like this: Note that, as $R\to\infty$, $$\left|\int_{R}^{R+2\pi}f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z\right|\ \begin{cases}\leq2\pi\cdot\frac{e^{cR}}{e^R-1}\to0,&c<1\\[0.5em]=e^{(c-1)R}\left|\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{cz}}{e^z+e^{-R}}\,\mathrm{d}z\right|\sim e^{(c-1)R}\left|\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{cz}}{e^z}\,\mathrm{d}z\right|\not\to0,&c\geq 1\end{cases}$$

Comment: So, indeed your maximum is not correct, and more importantly, divergence of an upper bound does not imply anything about the convergence/divergence of the original integral.

Comment: Thanks! I got an idea from this hint, which helps. :)